# Parse labeled param strings with Regex

Tags: regex

Can anyone help me with this one?

My objective here is to grab some info from a text file, present the user with it and ask for values to replace that info so to generate a new output. So I thought of using regular expressions.

My variables would be of the format: `{@<num>[|<value>]}`.

Here are some examples:

```
{@1}<br>
{@2|label}<br>
{@3|label|help}<br>
{@4|label|help|something else}<br><br>
```

So after some research and experimenting, I came up with this expression: `\{\@(\d{1,})(?:\|{1}(.+))*\}`

which works pretty well on most of the ocasions, except when on something like this:

```
{@1} some text {@2|label} some more text {@3|label|help}
```

In this case variables 2 & 3 are matched on a single occurrence rather than on 2 separate matches...

I've already tried to use lookahead commands for the trailing `}` of the expression, but I didn't manage to get it.

I'm targeting this expression for using into C#, should that further help anyone...

Comment: Did you try using a non-greedy match `(.+?)` instead of `(.+)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular expression which can be used would be something like

```
\{\@(\d+)(?:\|([^|}]+))*\}
```

This will prevent reading over any closing `}`.

Another possible solution (with slightly different behaviour) would be to use a non-greedy matcher `(.+?)` instead of the greedy version `(.+)`.

Note: I also removed the `{1}` and replaced `{1,}` with `+` which are equivalent in your case.

Comment: Also worked!
A bit more refined, as each argument is already splited. Perfect solution, in my opinion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I like the results from this one:

```
\{\@(\d+)(?:|\|(.+?))\}
```

This returns 3 groups. The second group is the number (1, 2, 3) and the third group is the arguments ('label', 'label|help').

I prefer to remove the `*` in favor of `|` in order to capture all the arguments after the first pipe in the last grouping.

Comment: It works! Thanks man!
I get 2 groups, 1 with the name, another with the args, which I can then split byt the "|".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\{\@(\d+)(?:\|[^|}]+)*\}
```

In C#:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(mystring,
                                        @"\{\@(\d+)(?:\|[^|}]+)*\}");
```

It prevents the label and help from eating the `|` or `}`.

```
match[0].Value => {@1}
match[0].Groups[0].Value => {@1}
match[0].Groups[1].Value => 1
match[1].Value => {@2|label}
match[1].Groups[0].Value => {@2|label}
match[1].Groups[1].Value => 2
match[2].Value => {@3|label|help}
match[2].Groups[0].Value => {@3|label|help}
match[2].Groups[1].Value => 3
```

Comment: Didn't work...
I only get one group with the number argument of the variable with this one. But it fixes my bug though :)

Comment: @Suriv, I guess I don't understand what you're trying to do.  When properly escaped, my regex matches the 3 braced tags in your example.  It puts the number in the first group.  See my updated answer.